# How AWS IAM with OpenID Connect works?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have just set up OpenId Connect Identity Provider for AWS IAM.
How does it work?
I've set up only audience (client id). How can I protect my EC2 instances ? or even protect AWS API Gateways if IAM don't have any client's secret?

Maybe I don't catching this but I wanted to use IAM to secure my REST API on different systems.

Does anyone know how to do it ? Maybe some course?